# hashCode() is never called when adding to Maps and Sets

Tags: apex, map, bug, hashcode, set

Given the following Apex class, which implements `equals()` and `hashCode()` as per the [Using Custom Types in Map Keys and Sets documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_collections_maps_keys_userdefined.htm):

```
public class Foo
{
    private Integer x;
    
    public Foo(Integer x)
    {
        this.x = x;
    }
    
    public Boolean equals(Object obj) 
    {
        System.debug('equals');
        
        if(obj instanceof Foo)
        {
            Foo f = (Foo)obj;
            return x == f.x;
        }
        
        return false;
    }

    public Integer hashCode() 
    {
        System.debug('hashCode');
        return x;
    }
}
```

When running the following in the Execute Anonymous window:

```
Foo f1 = new Foo(1);
Foo f2 = new Foo(2);

System.debug('Map');

Map<Foo, Boolean> m = new Map<Foo, Boolean>();

System.debug('put');
m.put(f1, true);
m.put(f2, true);

System.debug('get');
System.debug(m.get(f1));
System.debug(m.get(f2));

System.debug('Set');

Set<Foo> s = new Set<Foo>();

System.debug('add');
s.add(f1);
s.add(f2);

System.debug('contains');
System.debug(s.contains(f1));
System.debug(s.contains(f2));
```

I get the following output in the log:

```
10:20:47.109 (109419811)    USER_DEBUG  [4]|DEBUG|Map
10:20:47.113 (113647288)    USER_DEBUG  [8]|DEBUG|put
10:20:47.197 (197941404)    USER_DEBUG  [12]|DEBUG|equals
10:20:47.202 (202365558)    USER_DEBUG  [12]|DEBUG|get
10:20:47.220 (220325097)    USER_DEBUG  [12]|DEBUG|equals
10:20:47.245 (245972058)    USER_DEBUG  [12]|DEBUG|equals
10:20:47.250 (250500074)    USER_DEBUG  [13]|DEBUG  TRUE
10:20:47.267 (267329766)    USER_DEBUG  [12]|DEBUG|equals
10:20:47.271 (271834178)    USER_DEBUG  [14]|DEBUG|true
10:20:47.271 (271888873)    USER_DEBUG  [16]|DEBUG|Set
10:20:47.275 (275988792)    USER_DEBUG  [20]|DEBUG|add
10:20:47.296 (296012585)    USER_DEBUG  [12]|DEBUG|equals
10:20:47.301 (301160512)    USER_DEBUG  [24]|DEBUG|contains
10:20:47.324 (324164712)    USER_DEBUG  [12]|DEBUG|equals
10:20:47.351 (351133028)    USER_DEBUG  [12]|DEBUG|equals
10:20:47.357 (357265136)    USER_DEBUG  [25]|DEBUG|true
10:20:47.382 (382010122)    USER_DEBUG  [12]|DEBUG|equals
10:20:47.388 (388259431)    USER_DEBUG  [26]|DEBUG|true
```

As you can see, `hashCode()` is not called once, instead `equals()` is called against all existing members of the collection (ok, that's maybe not clear from the log, but increase the volumes and it's very clear, it's also take **forever** when the Map gets above about 10 elements) which goes contrary to this pair of statements in the [Map documentation](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_collections_maps.htm) as well as the standard Java implementation.

> - Unlike Java, Apex developers do not need to reference the algorithm that is used to implement a map in their declarations (for example, HashMap or TreeMap). **Apex uses a hash structure for all maps.**
> - **Uniqueness of map keys of user-defined types is determined by the `equals` and `hashCode` methods, which you provide in your classes.** Uniqueness of keys of all other non-primitive types, such as sObject keys, is determined by comparing the objects’ field values.

I'm sure my implementation of `hashCode()` is 'right' (other than being a terrible means of creating a hash) since the following produces the correct output:

```
Object o = new Foo(1);
System.debug(o.hashCode());
System.debug(System.hashCode(o));
```

Log output:

```
10:41:11.659 (659323616)    USER_DEBUG  [25]|DEBUG|hashCode
10:41:11.659 (659395719)    USER_DEBUG  [2]|DEBUG|1
10:41:11.745 (745368812)    USER_DEBUG  [25]|DEBUG|hashCode
10:41:11.745 (745439365)    USER_DEBUG  [3]|DEBUG|1
```

I am seeing this issue across multiple Orgs on multiple instances. Is this a bug with the platform? Has this worked correctly in previous releases?

Comment: @KeithC This is a cut down example which stems from the fact I've run this with larger values and am seeing the same behaviour (see my comment about it taking FOREVER to run with larger volumes). 20 keys takes about 6 seconds to insert in a simple loop, 100 keys often times out the developer console, other times it takes about a minute (and generates a 2mb log). Note: This issue only appears with classes as keys, SObjects and primitives work nice and quickly as you'd expect.

Comment: Hi Alex -- did you ever get anywhere with this? I was seeing performance problems with one of my classes and have boiled down the repro case to basically what you have above -- on orgs I have on na7 and na9, hashCode() is called. On na16 and na24, it isnt. I am going to open a case but if you have anything else to say about this, I'd like to include it! Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It took 2 months, but this is the "final" answer we got from Support on this topic. Note that the investigation by Tier 3 resulted in this Known Issue being filed which was ultimately the cause for our documented behavior (i.e. by setting a log filter override on a class with a hashCode()/equals() implementation, it effectively disabled hashCode() from being called)

Here's the Known Issue:

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000eMoeAAE

And here's the explanation on why FINEST vs. DEBUG makes a difference

> Here is a recap of the current issue:
>
> with log level = debug
>
> DEBUG|Final HashableClass.hashCodeCount=10
>   DEBUG|Final HashableClass.equalsCount=0
>
> with log level = finest
>
> DEBUG|Final HashableClass.hashCodeCount=0
>   DEBUG|Final HashableClass.equalsCount=45
>
> In this testcase, adding 10 HashableClass objects to a Set causes 10
>   hasCode() method calls because there are not any hash conflicts.
>
> However, if the log level is set to FINEST, a Set Interpreter Instance
>   is converted to a Set Wrapper Instance in order to log an event of a
>   static field's assignment at line#6 (hashables = new
>   Set(); ) in the HashableClassDemo class.
>
> When an object is added to a Set Wrapper Instance, we traverse the
>   entire list in it and compare objects for equality. That's why the
>   number of the equals() calls becomes 45 (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8
>   + 9).
>
> ========================
>
> The difference comes from underlying Map representations.
>
> Internally, we have 2 representations for Map.
>
> 1) One keeps the objects in a Map in the interpreter (apex) native
>   representation.And in this case, if the put() method is called to it,
>   uniqueness of keys are determined by using both of hashCode() and
>   equals(). (A value returned by the hashCode() method is used to
>   determine a bucket, and the equals() method is used to identify
>   objects in the same bucket.)
>
> 2) Once a Map is marshaled, the other representation is used.In this
>   representation, in the put() method call, we traverse all objects in a
>   Map and linearly check uniqueness of keys using the equals() method if
>   a user defined key is used.That's why you don't see the hashCode()
>   method calls but see the equals() method calls in your testcase. (In
>   your org, the Map object is marshaled when trying to generate a debug
>   message for local variable assignments.)
>
> However, the latter representation does not violate the Map contract.
>   Any method call defined in the Map class works as per doc.

This is the repro case that goes along with the investigation above:

```
public with sharing class HashableClass {
    public static Integer hashCodeCount = 0;
    public static Integer equalsCount = 0;

    private Integer simpleMember;

    public HashableClass(Integer val) {
        this.simpleMember = val;
    }

    public Integer hashCode(){
        hashCodeCount++;
        System.debug('entering HashableClass.hashCode hashCodeCount=' + hashCodeCount);
        return simpleMember;
    }

    public Boolean equals(Object other){
        equalsCount++;
        System.debug('entering HashableClass.equals equalsCount=' + equalsCount);
        if(other == null){
            return false;
        }
        if(!(other instanceof HashableClass)){
            return false;
        }
        return ((HashableClass)other).simpleMember == this.simpleMember;
    }
}

public with sharing class HashableClassDemo {
    private static Set<HashableClass> hashables;
    private static Set<HashableClass.InnerHashableClass> innerHashables;

    public static void demo() {
        hashables = new Set<HashableClass>();

        for(Integer i=0; i<10; i++){
            HashableClass h = new HashableClass(i);
            hashables.add(h);
        }

        System.debug('Final HashableClass.hashCodeCount=' + HashableClass.hashCodeCount);
        System.debug('Final HashableClass.equalsCount=' + HashableClass.equalsCount);
    }
}
```

Comment: "However, the latter representation does not violate the Map contract. Any method call defined in the Map class works as per doc." - This statement causes me problems, because in my eyes part of not violating the Map contract is that the implementation is performant. When hitting the second code path performance is a MAJOR issue, especially for tests (which it causes to fail).

Comment: You're preaching to the choir here -- this is an unacceptable answer but we went back to the well twice on this to get a better answer or documentation of this as a platform bug. Neither happened.

Comment: Thanks for this post, I thought I was going insane.  Can't believe Salesforce has allowed such an egregious bug to persist for 6 years!

Comment: I disagree that it doesn't break the contract, as the docs explicitly state, "Apex uses a hash structure for all maps." (and a bucket count of 1 isn't a hash map). https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_collections_maps.htm

Comment: This behaviour may not break the contract, but the inconsistency is very annoying. I had a bug in an equals method but my hashCode method was good. A unit test was failing as two objects were unexpectedly different (with different hashCodes). When I tried to debug the test, the Set I was using stopped calling hashCode and the test passed due the the bad equals method. This was hard to debug since it stopped failing every time I turned logging on!

Answer (score 3):

Taking your code and wrapping it in a test with counters for the calls confirms `hashCode` is called because the test passes. I don't know why you are experiencing different results but suggest you move to test cases to check behaviour.

**PS** See comment thread - different results on different instances.

```
@isTest
private class HashCodeTest {
    public class Foo
    {
        Integer equalsCalls = 0;
        Integer hashCodeCalls = 0;

        private Integer x;

        public Foo(Integer x)
        {
            this.x = x;
        }

        public Boolean equals(Object obj) 
        {
            equalsCalls++;
            System.debug('equals');

            if(obj instanceof Foo)
            {
                Foo f = (Foo)obj;
                return x == f.x;
            }

            return false;
        }

        public Integer hashCode() 
        {
            hashCodeCalls++;
            System.debug('hashCode');
            return x;
        }
    }

    @isTest
    static void testMap() {

        Foo f1 = new Foo(1);
        Foo f2 = new Foo(2);

        Map<Foo, Boolean> m = new Map<Foo, Boolean>();
        m.put(f1, true);
        m.put(f2, false);
        System.assert(f1.hashCodeCalls > 0);
        System.assert(f2.hashCodeCalls > 0);
    }

    @isTest
    static void testSet() {

        Foo f1 = new Foo(1);
        Foo f2 = new Foo(2);

        Set<Foo> s = new Set<Foo>();
        s.add(f1);
        s.add(f2);
        System.assert(f1.hashCodeCalls > 0);
        System.assert(f2.hashCodeCalls > 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting all sorts of strange going on with this. I did a direct copy-paste of your code, tests pass (using the setup menu test runner). I then duplicated the Foo class into a non-test class, Bar, copy-pasted to create 2 tests for it, all 4 pass. I then run the code for testMap in the Developer Console, assertion failed. Finally, I go back to the setup menu test runner, all tests fail. I've replicated this flow multiple times (resetting by deleting the classes) with the same results. Feels like a bug to me.

Comment: @AlexTennant Just tried the test again on na7 and it passed. But it fails on na15. Very scary.

Comment: Are you both using the same API-Version at all your tests?

Comment: @AlexTennant Tried both na7 and na15 again with the same results. My guess would be that the difference is which patches have been applied to the instances. Hard to imagine how any reasonable platform test suite would let a problem like this through though.

Comment: @AlexanderJohannes Yes, API 31 in all my recent ones, although I've tested this back to API 24 previously.

Comment: @AlexanderJohannes I'm consistently using 31 for my tests.

Comment: @KeithC I know, it's crazy that this has gone through QA and not been spotted, it's a HUGE performance degradation if you rely on this working. I may have to implement my own HashMap for the time being to guarantee I always get the correct behaviour.