# Unexpected results when using a custom class as key in Map

Tags: apex, map, hashcode

I thought I understood how maps are supposed to work. So, I thought I would try to be clever and use a custom class as the key in a map in Apex. The results, however have been unexpected.

It's so fundamental that I must be missing something stupid, but I can't see it yet. In the actual application, the custom class I'm using as a key is a bit like an XPath specifier, identifying an object in a tree by the path to that object.

Below, I've distilled it right down to something you can run as anonymous Apex, and still get results that baffle me:

```
Integer nCallsToEquals = 0;

public class HashingTest {
    private String s;

    public HashingTest(HashingTest ht) {
        this.s = ht.s;
    }

    public HashingTest(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    public Integer hashCode() {
        return s.hashCode();
    }

    public Boolean equals(Object o) {
        ++nCallsToEquals;
        if(o instanceof HashingTest) {
            return s == ((HashingTest)o).s;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}

HashingTest k1 = new HashingTest('a');
HashingTest k2 = new HashingTest('b');

System.debug('k1.hashCode(): ' + k1.hashCode());
System.debug('k2.hashCode(): ' + k2.hashCode());

Map<HashingTest, Integer> aMap = new Map<HashingTest, Integer>();

aMap.put(k1, 1);
aMap.put(k2, 2);

nCallsToEquals = 0;
aMap.get(k1);
System.debug('nCallsToEquals: ' + nCallsToEquals);
System.assertEquals(1, nCallsToEquals);
nCallsToEquals = 0;
aMap.get(k2);
System.debug('nCallsToEquals: ' + nCallsToEquals);
System.assertEquals(1, nCallsToEquals);

System.debug('aMap: ' + aMap);
System.debug('calling keySet()');
aMap.keySet();
System.debug('aMap: ' + aMap);

nCallsToEquals = 0;
aMap.get(k1);
System.debug('nCallsToEquals: ' + nCallsToEquals);
System.assertEquals(1, nCallsToEquals);
nCallsToEquals = 0;
aMap.get(k2);
System.debug('nCallsToEquals: ' + nCallsToEquals);
System.assertEquals(1, nCallsToEquals);
```

In my code, HashingTest is suitable for use as a key because it specifies implementations for  `hashCode()` and `equals()` (they just delegate to `String`).

And I have a counter to see how many times `equals()` gets called. This allows us to count the number of collisions in the hashmap implementation.

After populating the map, I output the hashcodes for the keys to make sure they are different (they are).

Then, I get the values back out of the map using the keys. I reset the counter before each `get()`, so that I can see how many times `equals()` is called.

The first time, `equals()` is called once for getting `k1` and once for `k2`. Then, after I call `keyset()`, it is called once for `k1` and twice for `k2`. As if `k1` and `k2` are now in the same bucket in the hashmap.

This seems like a triviality, but the numbers explode very quickly. I came to this because I have map with 185 entries where I need to access key-value pairs. I was iterating over the keyset and calling get() on each key. Due to this behaviour, it takes 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + 185 = 17,020 calls to equals() to achieve this.

Here's the debug output in its entirety:

```
15:48:47.1 (3318843)|USER_DEBUG|[32]|DEBUG|k1.hashCode(): 97
15:48:47.1 (3513197)|USER_DEBUG|[33]|DEBUG|k2.hashCode(): 98
15:48:47.1 (4144662)|USER_DEBUG|[42]|DEBUG|nCallsToEquals: 1
15:48:47.1 (4386196)|USER_DEBUG|[45]|DEBUG|nCallsToEquals: 1
15:48:47.1 (4749309)|USER_DEBUG|[47]|DEBUG|aMap: {HashingTest:[s=a]=1, HashingTest:[s=b]=2}
15:48:47.1 (4792183)|USER_DEBUG|[48]|DEBUG|calling keySet()
15:48:47.1 (5045209)|USER_DEBUG|[50]|DEBUG|aMap: {HashingTest:[s=a]=1, HashingTest:[s=b]=2}
15:48:47.1 (5180286)|USER_DEBUG|[54]|DEBUG|nCallsToEquals: 1
15:48:47.1 (5333300)|USER_DEBUG|[57]|DEBUG|nCallsToEquals: 2
```

A couple of updates:

1. I tried using `System.hashCode(s)` instead of `s.hashCode()` but it made no difference
2. This problem certainly looks related to [hashCode() is never called when adding to Maps and Sets](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46525/hashcode-is-never-called-when-adding-to-maps-and-sets) (as @keith-c answered below), but I don't believe it is entirely down to the same Known Issue (https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000eMoeAAE). I've rerun the code with all logging flags set to NONE, and put in assertions to check the value of `nCallsToEquals`. It then fails on the final assertion (getting `k2` after calling `keySet()`) and generates no debug log at all. If I set the logging flags to FINEST, then it fails on the second assertion (the first time we get `k2`, before calling `keySet()`), which is what I would expect after reading the Known Issue. To me, this looks like there ought to be a separate bug filed with SF for a call to `keySet()` changing the underlying representation of a map.

Comment: (I believe this is somehow related to order of iteration being [predictable](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_apex_maps_and_sets_iteration_order.htm))

Comment: I don't see how iteration order has anything to do with this?

Comment: This looks like a bug. nCallsToEquals should equal 0 the entire time. I'll ask around.

Comment: I would have expected 1 call to equals each time? Even if there's one entry in the bucket, then you still need to make sure it's not a hash collision? I did find this other question and known issue which might explain it: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46525/hashcode-is-never-called-when-adding-to-maps-and-sets In that question, they say there are two representations of map one of which does a full traversal

Comment: Does this also happen when you use the System.hashCode(obj) method for hashing arbitrary objects introduced lately?

Comment: @RobertSösemann I should have mentioned that in the question: I tried it but it made no difference

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aidan has already linked to the post that describes what I think is the likely cause: [hashCode() is never called when adding to Maps and Sets](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46525/hashcode-is-never-called-when-adding-to-maps-and-sets).

Running with the debug level turned down would confirm.

A key point from that:

> 2) Once a Map is marshaled, the other representation is used.In this
>   representation, in the put() method call, we traverse all objects in a
>   Map and linearly check uniqueness of keys using the equals() method if
>   a user defined key is used.That's why you don't see the hashCode()
>   method calls but see the equals() method calls in your testcase. (In
>   your org, the Map object is marshaled when trying to generate a debug
>   message for local variable assignments.)

with the supporting comment:

> However, the latter representation does not violate the Map contract.
>   Any method call defined in the Map class works as per doc.

I guess the view is that reasonable performance is not an explicit part of the contract...

Comment: 17k string comparisons shouldn't be a huge performance hit. Granted it won't be as fast as 2 (or 200 or whatever)

Comment: @AdrianLarson But we use maps with the intention of avoiding exponential cost growth. If a map with 1,000 entries is accessed inside a 1,000 item loop that's an exponentially growing cost of 1,000,000 not the linearly growing cost of 1,000 you would expect.

Comment: I wasn't running it with lots of debug enabled. I noticed that it did start calling equals() on every element when I switched it to FINEST, even the first time around. But, I don't think it's related to debug levels in the original scenario. Will have a bit more of a play because I think it's the same circumstance as the linked question, but with slight different conditions causing it.

Comment: Right, I've run some more tests playing with debug levels and it doesn't appear that debug levels are causing the problem (details in edit to the question). So, I don't think that the existing question fully explains this. @AdrianLarson I came to this via a CPU timeout, and seeing it take about 2s to iterate over my map of 185 values so it is definitely a problem in my real code. I've abstracted it out for the question, but hashCode() and equals() are a bit more expensive in the real code.

Comment: @Aidan Interesting. Thanks for sharing your results here. Information on these internal quirks is hard to come by and your investigations may well help others in the future.